# Can i move/mount all media files to S3 bucket (or other) for saving space in my web hosting storage?

Tags: media, amazon-web-services

Since my web hosting is not scale-able  and have not sufficient space for storing further images, i want to move all media files to external storage, is it possible?

i have read this thread

[Magento Media Assets in Amazon S3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/462/magento-media-assets-in-amazon-s3)

anyone had tried above solution and made it succuessfully?

Comment: This is the same question as the one you linked and does not qualify as a new question. If you want to draw attention to the question to get more answers, you can offer a bounty on it.

Comment: Go for a paid extension if you don't find any other solution working
https://magecomp.com/magento-2-amazon-s3.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com)? This service will automatically transfer your media files in the background. There is a free version with some limitations, so in case you have to host larger amounts of data you might have to opt-in for one of the paid plans.